# CSS-variables passed by styled-components applied to antd-component dissapears after compiling by webpack in production mode

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, antd, css-variables

I'm using Ant-design with styled-components and want to theming my app by css-variables.

```
package.json:
"dependencies": {
...
"antd": "^3.19.1",
"styled-components": "^4.2.1",
...
}
..."webpack": "^4.29.6",
"babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
...
```

```
.babelrc:
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ],
    ["styled-components", {
      "minify": false,
      "ssr": false,
      "pure": true
    }]
  ],
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

```js
import { Input } from "antd";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledInput = styled(Input)`
  && {
    background-color: var(--primaryColor, #fff);
  }
`;
```

When i run my app in "development" webpack mode - everything ok, result is:

```css
.ijJGje.ijJGje {
    background-color: var(--primaryColor,#fff);
}
```

then i changing webpack mode to "production", and result is:

```css
.ijJGje.ijJGje {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

I tried different settings of styled-components in .babelrc file.
It doesn't help me.

P.S. It turns out the problem is more serious. I can't pass most of css parameters(border for example) with css-variables at all, in this context. With default value or without.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Did You ever find a solution to this @Rellaxx ? I can't seem to get antd to play nice with react, webpack and styled components

Comment: I created an issue in SC git and they answered - that is CSS problem not their. So they will not do anything. I recommend do not use css variables with SC like in my example.